# Python - Error , iterating list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I get error iterating list of dictionaries
custom_list - list of dictionaries
each dictionary have 3 keys

```
for i in custom_list:
    for link, id, timestamp in i.items():
        print("id : ", id)
        print("link : ", link)
        print("timestamp : ",timestamp)
```

The error:

```
    for link, id, timestamp in i.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

if i print  ' i '  i can see i have 3 values
example of ' i ' dictionary print

```
{'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'}
```

Comment: You are trying to assign two values (dictionary item key and dictionary item value) to three variables (link, id, timestamp). That is not possible. You are probably looking for `i['id'],i['link'],i['timestamp']`.

Comment: can you show me how it should be written?

Comment: Obviously your assumption is incorrect - each dictionary does *not* have 3 keys.

Comment: @MarkRansom the assumption can be (and probably is) correct. `items()`, however does not produce keys, it produces key/value pairs which can't be unpacked into three variables. This error is not caused by the number of keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: @Mark of course, how silly of me to miss the obvious.

Comment: As a side note, please take a few seconds to read the tag descriptions before using them. [python 3.x] and [python 3.10] should only be used for questions that are *specific* to these versions - that is, where these versions would differ from the usual behavior of other versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i in the first for loop will give a dictionary so you can directly reference the key value pair without another for loop

```
for i in custom_list:
    print("id : ", i['id'])
    print("link : ", i['link'])
    print("timestamp : ",i['timestamp'])
```

If the dictionary's structure is dynamic and you want to iterate for all the key value pairs in the dictionary of current iteration you can add the following

```
for i in custom_list:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Comment: That code is going to bomb on any entry that is missing one of the 3 keys.

Comment: This one solved my error , if i understand correctly i tried iterate the key and value on the second loop that what made the error right ?

Comment: @MarkRansom, true. The check whether the key is there in the dict or not can be added before printing if there's a chance that this can happen.

Comment: @None, you can write `for key, value in i.items():` which will iterate for 3 iterations. ('id', 1), ('link', 'https://www.link.com/'), and ('timestamp', '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111')

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the approach initially taken is that `dict.items()` will return a list of tuples of key-value pairs (Ex: `[(key1, val1), (key2, val2)]`)

There are several approaches we can take in this scenario, using dictionary methods: `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()`.

dict.keys() => a list of the keys present in the dictionary 
dict.values() => a list of the values present in the dictionary 
dict.items() => a list of key-value pairs in tuples.

1. **We can take each key in the dictionary, and pick the value for each key from the dictionary**

```py
custom_list = [
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'},
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'}
]

for i in custom_list:
    for a in i.keys():
        print(i[a])
```

2. **Alternatively, if the arrangement of the keys are consistent through-out every dictionary in the array, you can just assign variables to each of the values as we loop through the outer array.**

```py
custom_list = [
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'},
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'}
]

for i in custom_list:
    (id_, link, timestamp) = i.values()
    print((id_, link, timestamp))
```

3. **If the items in the dictionaries are dynamic, we can take this approach**

```py
custom_list = [
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'},
    {'id': 1, 'link': 'https://www.link.com/', 'timestamp': '2022-03-25 01:11:11.11111111'}
]

for i in custom_list:
    for key, value in i.items():
        print(key, value)
```